# Can't load VGG16 Model Weights

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am using this code to make my own VGG16 network:

```
# build the VGG16 network
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(3, img_width, img_height)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_1'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th"))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_1'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering="th"))

# load the weights of the VGG16 networks
f = h5py.File(weights_path)
for k in range(f.attrs['nb_layers']):
    if k >= len(model.layers):
    # we don't look at the last (fully-connected) layers in the savefile
        break
    g = f['layer_{}'.format(k)]
    weights = [g['param_{}'.format(p)] for p in range(g.attrs['nb_params'])]
    model.layers[k].set_weights(weights)
f.close()
print('Model loaded.')
```

But when I call my method, it crashes:

> ValueError: Layer weight shape (3L, 3L, 3L, 64L) not compatible with
>   provided weight shape (64, 3, 3, 3)

I have set `K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')` but still it crashes. Please help.

Comment: Can you please specify which version of Keras you're using?

Comment: @hikaru '2.1.5' don;t know to solve this error quite frustrating

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded the [`vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels` weights](http://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5) then you should go with 'tf' ordering as

```
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
```